# Rails custom validation has errors but still saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a rails app to manage events and I want to add validation to check if an event overlaps with another.

Here's my custom validation code to check for overlapping events:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :full_date, :start_hour, :end_hour, :address

  validate :no_overlapping_events

  def no_overlapping_events
    overlap = false
    same_date = Event.where(:full_date => self.full_date).where("id != ?", self.id).where(:address => self.address)


    same_date.each do |t|
      if self.start_hour <= t.start_hour
        if self.end_hour >= t.start_hour
          overlap = true
          break
        end
      end 
    end

    if overlap == true
      errors.add(:base, "Can't have overlapping events!")
    end
  end
end
```

I can still create events that are overlapping and they're still being saved. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Your custom validation method "ends" too soon. Try:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :full_date, :start_hour, :end_hour, :address

  validate :no_overlapping_events

  def no_overlapping_events
    overlap = false
    same_date = Event.where(:full_date => self.full_date).where("id != ?", self.id).where(:address => self.address)

    same_date.each do |t|
      if self.start_hour <= t.start_hour
        if self.end_hour >= t.start_hour
          overlap = true
          break
        end
      end 
    end

    if overlap == true
      errors.add(:base, "Can't have overlapping events!")
    end
  end
end
```

Also, as a logic error, what about the case when:

```
self.start_hour > t.start_hour and self.start_hour < t.end_hour
```

Comment: I added the end but it's still able to save when it should not. I don't see how I'm making a logic error. For example, e2.start_hour < e1.start_hour BUT e2.end_hour > e1.start_hour. That is, e2 starts before e1 but e2's ending time is between e1's start time and end time.

Comment: I guess that depends on what you define "overlapping" as, so feel free to disregard that part. As to the end, rather than just adding the end, remove the one after the `same_date = Event.where...` line. But I guess, you did that or else you'd have a syntax error. Can you make sure of that anyway?

Comment: I just did. The full code is not finished and I only have part of it done. I want to add more logic to it but I first want to test one a single case. What's weird is that when I try to edit the saved record and give it an overlapping time slot, the validation actually kicks in and throws an error. But when I try to create a new record, the validation is not kicking in.

Comment: Does `overlap` get set to true?

Comment: Yes. I checked it on rails console by adding: puts overlap at the end.

Comment: Hmm.. when you create a new record, at the time of validation your record does not have an `id`, so I'm not sure if the `where id != self.id` part will work right.

Comment: We can move this to chat if you like

Comment: Well, thanks for the help Adnan but I have to go to sleep cuz I have class early tomorrow. Hopefully the solution will come to me in a dream :)

Comment: No problem. I think removing the `where("id != ?", self.id)` clause completely should work just fine. Since your current record hasn't saved yet, you shouldn't have to try to exclude it from the query. You can handle the update case by explicitly checking that `self.id.nil? or self.id != t.id`